# How to create dynamic column in Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Reading a book on Spark. I can create a Dataframe/Dataset of single column with multiple rows as follows

```
val df = spark.range(10).toDF
df.count             #=> 10
df.printSchema       #=> id: long (nullable = false)
```

Is there a way to dynamically create Dataframe/Dataset having multiple columns?

What I am trying to do is to create a dataframe with thousands of columns. So looking for ways to create them dynamically.

Comment: There's a lot of documentation on the Spark website https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html - including how to programmatically create Dataframes

Comment: Would love to hear from downvoters if they understood the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is to do the following

```
Seq(1 to 10 match{
  case Seq(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) => (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
}).toDF()
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|_1 |_2 |_3 |_4 |_5 |_6 |_7 |_8 |_9 |_10|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9  |10 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Edited**

If you want to do above *transformation* in *pyspark*, you can do the following

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame([tuple(list(range(1,11)))])
```

you should have the same `dataframe` as above

Comment: Takes me to a positive direction. But how would I generate thousands of columns if required?

Comment: using tuples as i did in the answer won't be possible as tuple100 is not defined. What I can suggest you is to use case classes and create dataset.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, could you please show me the above example in its equivalent python code?

Comment: Brilliant!  I guess `sqlContext.createDataFrame([range(1,11)])` is adequate.

Comment: great !! Actually I am also a beginner in pyspark :)